# How to find the size of Object and show it on screen

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Is there any way through which we can show object size on screen while scaling in and out Object, please give me a simple example thanks.

Comment: I would make your question more clear (what do you mean, size? As in dimensions?), and show at least an attempt and what is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can get your object size like this:

```
public double GetObjectSize(Object Obj)
{
     using (var m = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
     {
     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter b = new
     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
     b.Serialize(m, Obj);
     double size = Convert.ToDouble(m.Length);
     return size;
    }
}
```

But consider that not all objects are serializable. And it will not serialize nested objects too deep.

Comment: Haha, really good answer, you made my day :D

Comment: Lol, I doubt the memory size was the goal :D